# Unable to login to mongodb docker container remotly

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm running docker-compose on my AWS EC2 machine, and for some reason, I cannot log in to the MongoDB instance remotely.

I'm using the MongoDB Compass Community application to log in with the details below:
`mongodb://username:password@myserver.com:27017` but unfortunately I'm receiving the message `connection time out`

My backend application can communicate with the MongoDB container using this way:
`mongodb://username:password@mongodb:27017`

this is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
 version: '3.6'
    
    services:
    backend:
        image: backendimage:1.0.0
        container_name: backend
        restart: always
        ports:
        - '8999:8999'
          - '5000:5000'
        links:
         - mongodb
    environment:
            NODE_ENV: development
          API_PORT: 5000
         MONGO_URI: mongodb://username:password@mongodb:27017
             TOKEN_KEY: token
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: always
    expose:
        - 27017
    ports:
        - '27017:27017'
    environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
        - ./conf/mongodb:/data/db
    
    volumes:
      projectvolume:
        external: true
```

This is the Security Group associated with that machine:
[image]

Please let me know if I have missed something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whether this helps https://indianceo.medium.com/how-to-connect-to-your-remote-mongodb-server-68725a8e53f ?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar, I have tried to fetch the file `/etc/mongod.conf` to be out side of the container and modify it but I was unsuccessful..

Answer (score 0):

I presume your application side was on the same environment with MongoDB services in AWS environment, while your MongoDB Compass was installed on your local laptop/computer. The connection timeout issue means there is something that blocked port 27017 from the host where MongoDB Compass is installed to the EC2 instance where MongoDB resides.

Does your EC2 instance where the docker MongoDB reside have public IP address?

The basic connectivity check is by Telnet, port 27017 from your end to the EC2 instance. Otherwise there might be the firewall in the AWS platform of the internet that is not opened yet for port 27017 or the EC2 does not have public connectivity.